# Java 8 List.sort usage

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) class in Java 8 has a new method `sort` added to it. Could anyone please clarify when should I prefer to use this as opposed to `Collections.sort(..)` method?

Answer (score 4):

There is no functional difference because `Collections.sort(list)` calls `list.sort(null)` and `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` calls `list.sort(comparator)`.

So it's just a matter of style - when providing your own comparator, calling sort on the list is probably more natural and readable than using an external static method.

However if you just want to sort the list in natural order, `Collections.sort(list)` is maybe clearer than `list.sort(null)`.

Comment: Does anyone know why there is no `list.sort()`?

Comment: @user4235730, `list.sort()` is unsafe: you could safe non-comparable list and compiler would not stop you. Actually `list.sort(null)` is also unsafe, so it's preferred to use `Collections.sort(list)` or `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, so if you happen to pass the list of non-comparable elements you will have a compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

You should go for [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-).

Example of using `List.sort`, to sort a list of String with respect to the length of the elements:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aa", "aaa", "a"));
list.sort(comparing(String::length));
```

`Collections.sort()` was the pre-Java 8 way of doing this. Note that there is no real difference between the two. If you take a look at [`Collections.sort`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29) source code, you can notice that it calls `list.sort`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    list.sort(c);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems `Collections.sort` is delegated to `List.sort` in JDK1.8.

Comment: There is nothing which `List.sort` does better regarding “to take advantage of lambda expressions” than `Collections.sort`. The advantage of `List.sort` is that `List` implementations can override it and provide more efficient implementations, e.g. `ArrayList` eliminates the copying step of the default implementation by sorting its internal array directly. Since `Collections.sort` delegates to `List.sort`, it doesn’t matter which method you use, you’ll gain that advantage in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Though you can use the `List.sort(Comparator)` method, the main purpose of this method is overriding. Before Java-8 the sorting of every `List` was somewhat ineffective. First the list was dumped into array via `toArray()` method, then the array was sorted and finally the list was updated via `ListIterator.set`. In Java-8 this is the default behavior implemented in `List.sort(Comparator)` default method. However you may change it in subclasses if you can provide more efficient algorithm. Examples:

- `ArrayList` and `Arrays.asList()` provide own `sort` implementation which directly sorts the internal array, thus you don't need to copy back and forth.
- `CopyOnWriteArrayList` just can be sorted now! Try the following code:

  ```
  List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "c", "b"));
  Collections.sort(list);
  ```

  In Java-7 it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`, because supporting `ListIterator.set` contradicts the idea of this list (every iterator iterates the independent snapshot). In Java-8 the `ListIterator.set` is still unsupported, but this code works correctly due to custom sort implementation.
- `Collections.singletonList` and `Collections.emptyList` just do nothing (sorting 0 or 1 element is a no-op) which is certainly faster than creating a one-element or zero-element array, sort it and iterate over list to set the value back.
- `Collections.unmodifiableList` now just throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. Prior to Java-8 you got the exception only after dumping the immutable list to the array, sorting the array and starting to write it back.

---

Here's an example which may be useful in user code. Suppose that you want to create a mapped view of some list:

```
public class MappedList<T, R> extends AbstractList<R> {
    private final List<T> source;
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper;

    public MappedList(List<T> source, Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
        this.source = source;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public R get(int index) {
        return mapper.apply(source.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return source.size();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "foo", "bb", "bar", "qq");
List<Integer> mappedList = new MappedList<>(list, String::length);
System.out.println(mappedList); // prints [1, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

Works fine, but trying `Collections.sort(mappedList);` you will get `UnsupportedOperationException` (`set` operation does not work as you cannot reverse the mapping function). However if you implement the `sort()` method in `MappedList`, you will be able to sort it correctly (changing the original list):

```
@Override
public void sort(Comparator<? super R> c) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Comparator<? super T> comparator = c == null ? 
        Comparator.comparing((Function<? super T, ? extends Comparable<Object>>) mapper) : 
        Comparator.comparing(mapper, c);
    source.sort(comparator);
}

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "foo", "bb", "bar", "qq");
List<Integer> mappedList = new MappedList<>(list, String::length);
Collections.sort(mappedList);
System.out.println(mappedList); // prints [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
System.out.println(list); // prints [a, bb, qq, foo, bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it when providing your own comparator. For instance:

```
list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Instead of:

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

List class as part of JSR 335 changes and we can make use of that method to sort the list:

//Using sort method in List.

personList.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.firstName.compareTo(p2.firstName));

--before java 8 we can used this tye only---
Collections.sort(personList, (p1, p2) -> p1.firstName.compareTo(p2.firstName));